# Specify runtime for self container .Net Core app in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core

I'm working on a .Net Core app, which I aim to run in production in a docker container.

I'm targeting the `netcoreapp1.0` framework. When building and running the application in the official .Net Core SDK image, everything works as expected.

The next step is to have a self contained app and use the official runtime image from Microsoft instead, as they recommend [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/).

What I understand is you have to specify which runtimes you want to include in the `runtime section` in your `project.json`.

My question is: Which runtime do `microsoft/dotnet:runtime` use under the hood for their latest image version?

There are a lot of different i.e Ubuntu runtimes to targets to choose from on [Microsoft Docs Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog):

- ubuntu.14.04-x64
- ubuntu.14.10-x64
- ubuntu.15.04-x64
- ubuntu.15.10-x64
- ubuntu.16.04-x64
- ubuntu.16.10-x64

The application will run as a Linux Container, NOT a Windows Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - `debian.8-x64`. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks, just found it myself here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/tree/master/dotnetapp-selfcontained